# hyphenating any-time

Tags: hyphenation

Is it ok to hyphenate "any time".

The context is in a sentence like:

```
We are available any time, any where
```

Can it be acceptably written?

```
We are available any-time, any-where
```

or should it be?

```
We are available anytime, anywhere
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anywhere is **always** one word.  Don't use any where or any-where.

[When you use anytime as an adverb, it should be one word.](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/anytime-any-time/)

> You can call me *anytime*.

This is how you are using it, so it should be one word.

When using a preposition, such as at, or talking about an amount time, then you should write any time as two words.

> You can call her at *any time*.
>
> Do you have *any time* to talk?

**So the correct answer is:**

> We are available anytime, anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

It should be:

We are available anytime, anywhere, without hyphenation.

However, it can be acceptably written as:

We are available any time, anywhere.

or

We are available any-time, anywhere

http://www.grammarbook.com/punctuation/hyphens.asp

'Anywhere', in your context cannot be split into 2 separate words.

Comment: Do you have any evidence for separating any time into two words?  The adverb anytime is always one word.  Any time is not an adverb, nor is any-time.  Nor does the link you included support your usage of any-time.  What rule from that website do you think applies here?

Comment: A quick search of the OED has entries for 'anytime' and 'any time'.

It would appear that anytime is a more modern contraction of any time.

http://www.oed.com/search?searchType=dictionary&q=anytime&_searchBtn=Search

Comment: That is very interesting, thank you for sharing.  But it doesn't really help answer the question for Charlie Smith, as they are most likely looking to speak modern English.